# Android user interface inheritance

Tags: android, user-interface, inheritance, xamarin.android

I'm new to android programming and don't know what is the right direction for my problems solution. I played around for five days to get on the right track but have still no answer. I guess there are a couple of post out there, that contain the required information, but obviously, I did not find the correct search input, to get them listed.

**Here is my problem:**
As I come from *C#* and *WinForms*, I'm used to develop user interfaces by inheritance. How is the intended way in android?

**An example:**
I have a main form `FormBase` that contains an exit button and a place holder for further gui components. Then I have two classes `FormA` and `FormC`, that both inherit from `FormBase`. 
`FormA` implements a listox on the placeholder of `FormBase`. 
`FormC` implements some textboxes and buttons (could be anything else).

The main application logic now switches between `FormA` and `FormC`, depending on the applications state.

To make my question more specific, how is such an behaviour implemented in android? When the application is started, it will connect to some kind of network service. This service will tell the application what *Dialog/Activity/Fragment* is currently active. Changing from `FormA` to `FormC` can be initiated over network!

What is the 'clean' and 'meant to be' way in android to write such applications. As the android framework design is not compareable to .NET winforms, I expect something, that can be completely different.

Thanks for your time reading this post.

Pix

Comment: *I expect something, that can be completely different.* - good, forget all about winforms. Make yourself familiar with fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments you might use them for your use case

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thank you Tim, I already did some research on fragments, but I'm not getting the right drive to how I can use them for inheritance. I find no way to inherit designs. In a fragment, there seems to be only a single inflate call to a (fixed) layout file.

Comment: fragments are hosted in an activity. The activity normally contains the shared stuff like bottom navigation and toolbar. The center of the screen can be fragments which can be replaced

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here, because the question itself remains the same. I just have an idea that maybe solve my problem. So I think that this post should be commented separately. Maybe my idea is against all design rules?! Let me know what you think about it.

The description is a little bit tricky, so I hope you understand what I mean.

> Just as a side note. I'm writing the code with Xamarin C#. But the structure should be comparable to android java code.

Okay, let's go...

### Layouts

- I have an activity with a layout xml that has a FrameLayout (@id/frame_base) as an placeholder for the fragments.
- I have a layout xml (fragment_base.axml) that has two FrameLayouts (@id/frame_left and @id/frame_right) as placeholders for upcoming fragments.
- I have a layout xml (fragment_A.axml) the has just a huge button with the text 'A'.
- I have a layout xml (fragment_B.axml) the has just a huge button with the text 'B'.

The idea is, that the placeholder `frame_base` will by inflated by the xml layout `fragment_base`, which contains the placeholder `frame_left`, that will be inflated by the xml layout `fragment_A` or `fragment_B`.

### Fragments

- I have a `FragmentBase` that derives from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`.
- I have a `FragmentA` that derives from `FragmentBase`.
- I have a `FragmentB` that derives from `FragmentBase`.

In the `FragmentA::OnCreateView(..)` method, I forward the call to the base class `FragmentBase::OnCreateView(..)`, which will inflate the viewgroup container with the `fragment_base` xml layout. We remember, this layout contains a placeholder with the id `frame_left`. We can 'find' the placeholder after `FragmentBase::OnCreateView(..)` returns with the inflated view. Having the `frame_left` view, we inflate it with the `fragment_A` xml layout.

In the FragmentB, we do exact the same thing. Of course we use the according 'B' files and classes.

Here is some code...

**class FragmentA**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  // Inflate frame_base
  var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

  // Inflate frame_left
  var leftFrame = view.FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Resource.Id.frame_left);
  inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_A, leftFrame, true); // The 'true' is important!

  return view;
}
```

**class FragmentBase**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_base, container, false);
}
```

### Activity

For this solution I need one activity. For testing purpose I used some toolbar buttons to switch between FragmentA and FragmentB. The important thing for me is, that I'm now able to instantiate FragmentA and the underlying layout and logic of FrameBase is also generated. Have a quick look in the code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

  // ... do some stuff here, that is really not important for this post...

  // Get the FrameManager (in Java this is like: FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  var fragmentManager = this.SupportFragmentManager; 

  // Start transaction
  var transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

  // Add a new fragment of type FragmentA that derives from FragmenBase.
  transaction.Add(Resource.Id.frame_base, new FragmentA(), "FrgmA");

  // Make it happen
  transaction.Commit();
}

private void OnToolbarButton_A()
{
  // Replace current fragment by FragmentA
  var fragmentManager = this.SupportFragmentManager;
  var transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
  transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.frame_base, new FragmentA(), "FrgmA");
  transaction.Commit();
}

private void OnToolbarButton_B()
{
  // Replace current fragment by FragmentB
  var fragmentManager = this.SupportFragmentManager;
  var transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
  transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.frame_base, new FragmentB(), "FrgmB");
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

### Conclusion

That's it and ehh ... it seems to work. 
But I'm not sure if this layout/class juggling is the intended android framework way of life.

Let me know what you think? Maybe you have better solutions?